# If $3$ divides the decimal digit sum of $n$ then $3$ divides $n$ (casting out threes)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a trick I learnt in primary school, but never gave it much thought. Here's how I formulate it:
$$
n = \sum_{j=0}^{m} x_j 10^{m-j}
$$
is a decimal expansion of some integer $n$ such that 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{m} x_j = r 
$$
such that $3|r$, then $3|n$. Or, $r= 3k$ and $n=3i$ with $k \neq i$. I thought about it for some time, but didn't get any intuition.

Comment: Write, e.g., $234=2(99+1)+ 3(9+1)+4\cdot1  = (2\cdot 99+3\cdot 9) +(2+3+4)$.

Comment: This is a special case of casting out nines - see the linked duplicate. Also you had "divides" in the wrong order: e.g. $n$ is even iff $2$ divides $n\ $ (not $n$ divides $2)\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Take the difference
$$n-r = \sum_{j=0}^{m} x_j (10^{m-j}-1)$$
and note that $3$ (but also 9) divides $(10^{m-j}-1)$.

Comment: OK, so it boils down to expanding the decimal term: $10^{m-j} = (1+9)^{m-j} = \sum_{i=0}^{m-j} 9^{i}$, then all terms but one are multiples of 3 and the first term is $x_j$ for all $j$, hence the sum. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Yes! That's right.